# Status bar Message Not shown on hosted website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have used below script to show message on status bar in browser.

```
If Session("UserName") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim strUserMessage As String = Session("UserName").ToString & ", Welcome to ABC Application"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "strUser", "<script>window.status = '" & strUserMessage & "' </script>")
    End If
```

However, this message is properly shown on locahost/intranet.

But whenever we have hosted this site on internet. This message is not shown.

Do we have to make certain configuration settings ???

Comment: Please at least research it before asking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status

Comment: Some years now browser did not show message on message bar - mainly for security reasons - to let the user actually see the action that is made when is over a link